# VB6 - How to execute multiple SQL queries in one call

Tags: sql-server, vb6, ado

I have an old slow procedure in VB6 using ADO to run many sql queries in many calls. Its taking too many hours. I want to test if sending all queries in one single query (most of them are just update or insert) to save network and calling time. How can I implement this, and also suggests if this would save time and boost performance?

```
    qry = "Update table1 Set col1 = 'eerere' Where 1=1"
    qry = qry & vbCrLf & "  AND MyID = " & MyID & vbCrLf
    ExecSQL qry, DBCon, adAsyncExecute

    qry = "Insert Into TableMain"
    qry = qry & "Select  col1,col2,col3 from Table2 Where 1=1"
    qry = qry & vbCrLf & "  AND MyID = " & MyID & vbCrLf
    ExecSQL qry, DBCon, adAsyncExecute

    qry = "Update table5 Set col1 = 'eerere' Where 1=1"
    qry = qry & vbCrLf & "  AND MyID = " & MyID & vbCrLf
    ExecSQL qry, DBCon, adAsyncExecute
```

Comment: Why not move this to a stored procedure? Then all your code is one place. And please consider parameterizing your queries. The pattern you have here is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Why is it taking hours? High volume? doing row-by-agonizing-row insert/updates? How fast does it need to be?

Comment: Yes that was my first idea. But code is too complicated and cannot take risk to have 1000 bugs. Already analysed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine them into one call by separating the commands with a semi-colon:

```
qry = "Update table1 Set col1 = 'eerere' Where 1=1"
qry = qry & vbCrLf & "  AND MyID = " & MyID & "; " & vbCrLf

qry = qry & "Insert Into TableMain"
qry = qry & "Select  col1,col2,col3 from Table2 Where 1=1"
qry = qry & vbCrLf & "  AND MyID = " & MyID & "; " & vbCrLf
```

It will probably give you some small performance improvement, if it doesn't cause any errors.

Comment: You're not concatenating the second query - should be `qry = qry & "Insert Into TableMain"`.

Comment: @MarkL Good catch.   Fixed.